# Using a VB Function as a SqlDataSource SelectParameter value

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, sqldatasource

in my code behind i have a function getEmail() that returns an email address, in the front end i have a sql data source selectcommand that grabs info according to the email address. as of now the email address is hardcoded i was wondering how to put getEmail() in to the selectcommand.

**VB**

```
    Public Function getEmail() As String
     Dim x As PublicProfile
     x= UserProfileContext.Current.UserInfo
    Return x.LoginName.ToString()
   End Function
```

front end

```
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" SelectCommand="select Count(ID)nums from revs where Email='jon@usa.com' and Source='PUB' and Status='a'"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I tried putting <% =getEmail() %> instead of the email but had no luck

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" SelectCommand="select Count(ID)nums from revs where Email='<% =getEmail() %>' and Source='PUB' and Status='a'"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Easy but prolix so I link MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad%28v=vs.140%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. In short use SQL parameters and fill them when page loads.

Comment: im reading that now but im not sure how to use my function to change the select parameter

Comment: When you say you "had no luck," what happened? Blanks, errors, bats flying out of the screen :) ?

Comment: lol it just shows nothing as if i entered nothing as an email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parameterize your query, modify your SqlDataSource markup as follows to add an "@Email" SelectParameter:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource> 
      ID="SqlDataSource1" 
   runat="server" 
   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
   SelectCommand="select Count(ID)nums from revs where Email=@EMail and  
                  Source='PUB' and Status='a'">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

In your codebehind/Page_Load(), try adding the following (before your binding) to place a value into the SelectParameter defined in the  markup, which is (in turn) provided by your function:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("Email").DefaultValue = getEmail()
```

Comment: beautiful my friend, stack needs more like u